# How to defeat Lynx?

Tags: shadow-fight-2

In Shadow Fight 2, the first boss you must defeat is called Lynx. defeat him! I have upgraded all my weapons and armor to max for a level 6 player. I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work. How can I defeat Lynx?

Comment: Did you upgraded your weapons too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Equipment

1. Complete offers to gain gems and buy gem gear.
2. Play survival until you reach level 7. (What I did)

---

## Techniques

1. Upon Lynx's invincibility, keep away from him and attack using only simple moves (avoid combos and long range attacks at all costs)
2. Duck against his throwing knives (jumping leaves you vulnerable for a second knife)
3. **Lynx's weakness?** Long/medium range low attacks. Strike low with to prevent him for hooking you, and long range attacks help stop the throwing knives.

Answer (score 0):

Use daggers and upgrade your armor,helm and daggers to level 7.
Let him not attack you keep him to the ground. When he becomes invisible,just keep hitting him.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy

1. when Lynx throws a projectile try to dodge it, if you don't hopefully it is a ninja star.
2. When he turns invisible your shadow will look at the direction of Lynx. To attack him I suggest using the leg sweep move to keep him knocked to the ground and use Critical attacks to make him stop using the cloaking spell
3. When up close keep hitting him with direct head hits.
4. Try to make him unable to attack back as well.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to defeat Lynx, it is very easy. Last time, I also met a problem like this,  I will teach you my method to defeat Lynx.First, when he tried to super slash, you don't move, block his strike.When he is trying to throw ranged weapons, try to duck or roll.If he's trying to cast his invisible spell just jump everywhere or just simply strike him with your weapons.This is all I can teach, good luck, I'm now going to defeat Hermit.

Comment: How exactly do you block a strike?

Comment: @Scribblenautical To block enemy attacks hold the joystick away from them. Blocking over and over is the best defensive act. Wait for the enemy to attack you while blocking. When the enemy is in front of you, use throws elbows knees over attacks.